# Aggregating start and end of consecutive detection to know total duration

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have been running an algorithm to detect some sound on some audiofiles. The resulting dataset contains the time at which detection have started and ended. However, the predictions are made every 3 seconds and I would like to aggregate the dataset to obtain the length of the detection. So if `start` at row n+1 is equal to `end` at row n then the rows should be aggregated.

Here is how my dataset look like:

```py
data = {
    'filename': ['file1', 'file1', 'file1', 'file1', 'file1', 'file2', 'file2', 'file2', 'file2', 'file2'],
    'start': [21, 24, 27, 44, 60, 34, 37, 55, 58, 120],
    'end':  [24, 27, 30, 47, 63, 37, 40, 58, 61, 123]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

And here is what I am hoping to obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you've asked:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'filename': ['file0', 'file1', 'file1', 'file1', 'file1', 'file1', 'file2', 'file2', 'file2', 'file2', 'file2'],
    'start': [18,21, 24, 27, 44, 60, 34, 37, 55, 58, 120],
    'end':  [21, 24, 27, 30, 47, 63, 37, 40, 58, 61, 123]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['continuation'] = (df.filename == df.filename.shift()) & (df.end.shift() == df.start)
df['keep'] = ~df.continuation.shift(-1).astype(bool)
df.at[df.index[-1], 'keep'] = True
df.start = df.start[~df.continuation]
df.start = df.start.fillna(method="ffill").astype(int)

df = ( df[df.keep]
    .assign(duration=df.end - df.start)
    .drop(columns=['continuation', 'keep']).reset_index(drop=True) )

print(df)
```

Explanation:

- in a new `continuation` column, label rows with a boolean indicating whether they continue an earlier sound detection
- in a new `keep` column, flag the final row of each detection (namely, each row that immediately precedes a non-continuation row, as well as the final row in the dataframe) as the rows we will eventually keep
- ensure that the `start` value of each row we intend to keep is updated with the `start` value from the first row of the same sound detection; do this by nulling out `start` values in all continuation rows, then using `ffill` to forward fill these nulls
- filter only the rows with `keep` equals True, calculate `duration` from `end` and `start`, and drop the intermediate columns `continuation` and `keep`
- use reset_index() to renumber the rows.

Output:

```
   filename  start  end
0     file0     18   21
1     file1     21   24
2     file1     24   27
3     file1     27   30
4     file1     44   47
5     file1     60   63
6     file2     34   37
7     file2     37   40
8     file2     55   58
9     file2     58   61
10    file2    120  123
  filename  start  end  duration
0    file0     18   21         3
1    file1     21   30         9
2    file1     44   47         3
3    file1     60   63         3
4    file2     34   40         6
5    file2     55   61         6
6    file2    120  123         3
```

Note: I have added an initial row with filename `file0` whose `end` value matches the `start` value of the next row (with filename `file1`) to demonstrate that there is no aggregation across different files.

---

Alternative code:

```py
df['continuation'] = (df.filename == df.filename.shift()) & (df.end.shift() == df.start)
df['keep'] = ~df.continuation.shift(-1).astype(bool)
df.at[df.index[-1], 'keep'] = True
df['groupnum'] = df.keep.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
gb = df.groupby('groupnum')
df = pd.concat([gb.first()[['filename','start']], gb.last()['end']], axis=1).rename_axis(index=None)
df['duration'] = df.end - df.start
print(df)
```

Explanation:

- after creating the `continuation` and `keep` columns as above, use `cumsum` to assign a sound detection index to each row in a new column `groupnum`
- use `groupby` to group the rows by `groupnum`
- use `concat` to take `start` and `end` from each group's first and last row, respectively
- leave the `groupnum` index as is, nulling out its name with `rename_axis`, and calculate a new `duration` column.

Comment: Do you need any more help with your question?

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please consider marking it as "accepted".